# Truncate older logs after the log file size reaches a particular size

Tags: linux, logging, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, logrotate

I've my application running on one of the Docker containers in AWS Fargate(serverless compute engine) where I'm using a bind volume to `tee` application logs as follows:

`/app.bin 2>&1 | tee /logs/app.log`

[The AWS bind volumes can grow maximum up to 200 GB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bind-mounts.html), so I want to truncate the older logs once the size of my log file i.e. `app.log` reaches to some specific number(let's say `190 GB`).

Any ideas on how do we achieve this log-rotation?
I figured out that maybe I can use `logrotate` command along with `tee`. What are the other ways? How should I do it?

Comment: By "truncate" you mean stop logging to app.log, rename app.log, and then create a new app.log? It almost sounds like you want newer log entries to displace the oldest log entries so the app.log remains at 190GB once its reached 190GB, which is different

Comment: @barrycarter I want the total size of `/logs/app.log` to be under `190 GB` at any given point in time. So once the size of `app.log` reaches `190GB`, I would like to delete the oldest `10GB` worth of logs from `app.log` to make the `app.log` size to `180GB`. Again, when it reaches `190`, truncate the oldest `10GB` and so on... And I want to do all this with a single log file, i.e. `app.log`

Comment: OK, truncating a file from the start is ugly (as far as I know). Consider using 19 10GB logs and then rotate those so the oldest is deleted.

Comment: I'd consider something substantially smaller than 10GB. Think about the fact that you may at some point actually have to look at these files; are you working on a machine that is going to be able open a 10GB file to memory? Are you going to be able to effectively filter through the tens of millions of lines that 10GB could be?